# Can I use 'OR' statement under CASE WHEN THEN clause?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table *my_table* on snowflake:

| COMPANY | TRANSACTIONS |
| --- | --- |
| AMERICAN | 321-AMERICAN EAGLE 123 |
| NIKE | 080* NIKE_74093 |
| AMERICAN | 00 AMERICANEAGLE_42 |
| ADIDAS | 0101ADIDAS **093 |
| AMERICAN | 987 AMERICAN AIRLINE_4 |
| AMERICAN | 17 AMERICAN-EXPRESS 02 |
| AMERICAN | 09 AMERICAN-EAGLE_42 |
| AMERICAN | 0* AMERICANAIRLINE **7 |
| AMERICAN | 101AMERICAN EXPRESS *9 |
| COCA | 98*COCA COLA __4237 |

The COMPANY column is the company's abbreviation (basically the first word of the company's name).

The TRANSACTIONS column is the transaction names that showed in my dataset. There will be some prefixes and suffixes in each transaction name due to different processing methods.

For the *Company* column value "American", there could be "American Eagle", "American Airline", "American Express", etc. in the *Transactions* column, correspondingly.

**What should I do if I only want to keep the rows with transactions from *American Eagle* while the Company column value is "*American*" with all other companies' transactions?**

Resulting table I am looking for:

| COMPANY | TRANSACTIONS |
| --- | --- |
| AMERICAN | 321-AMERICAN EAGLE 123 |
| NIKE | 080* NIKE_74093 |
| AMERICAN | 00 AMERICANEAGLE_42 |
| ADIDAS | 0101ADIDAS **093 |
| AMERICAN | 09 AMERICAN-EAGLE_42 |
| COCA | 98*COCA COLA __4237 |

Below is my SQL query trying to solve the problem, the **challenge** I got here is even for American Eagle, the Transactions column value could be like **"AMERICAN EAGLE"(space in the middle)** , **"AMERICANEAGLE" (no space)** , **"AMERICAN-EAGLE" (hyphen in the middle)** , etc. Therefore, I am trying to use CASE WHEN ... THEN (...OR...) statements in my SQL Query. However, the below query doesn't work and pops up errors.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM my_table
    WHERE 
     transactions LIKE CONCAT('%',
     CASE WHEN company = 'AMERICAN' THEN ('AMERICAN EAGLE' OR 'AMERICANEAGLE' OR 'AMERICAN-EAGLE')
     ELSE company END, '%')
```

Can I use the "OR" statement under the "THEN" clause since the CASE WHEN THEN only returns a single value?

Answer (score 1):

I would handle company 'AMERICAN' separately with normal OR-conditions to include the three cases you have, and then all other companies as such:

```
    with my_table as (
    select 'AMERICAN' as COMPANY,   '321-AMERICAN EAGLE 123' as TRANSACTIONS
    union all select 'NIKE',    '080* NIKE_74093'
    union all select 'AMERICAN',    '00 AMERICANEAGLE_42'
    union all select 'ADIDAS',  '0101ADIDAS **093'
    union all select 'AMERICAN',    '987 AMERICAN AIRLINE_4'
    union all select 'AMERICAN',    '17 AMERICAN-EXPRESS 02'
    union all select 'AMERICAN',    '09 AMERICAN-EAGLE_42'
    union all select 'AMERICAN',    '0* AMERICANAIRLINE **7'
    union all select 'AMERICAN',    '101AMERICAN EXPRESS *9'
    union all select 'COCA',    '98*COCA COLA __4237'
    )
    select *
    from my_table
    where (  ( company = 'AMERICAN' and (transactions like '%AMERICAN EAGLE%'
                                      or transactions like '%AMERICANEAGLE%'
                                      or transactions like '%AMERICAN-EAGLE%')
             )
          OR company <> 'AMERICAN'
          );
```